# How to get parent table of selection in word using office.js 1.1?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

Is anyone aware of a way to get access to the parent table of a selection in a version of Word that only has access to the 1.1 js api? We've been developing with 1.3 in mind, but must now also support the earlier version, rendering the following code broken:

```
async checkForInsideTable(ctx: Word.RequestContext, sel: Word.Range) {
  let pt = sel.parentTable;
  ctx.load(pt);

  try {
    await ctx.sync();
    this.tableObject = pt;
    return true;
  } catch {
    this.tableObject = null;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Over the past week we've tried a lot of different approaches, such as using bindings, wrapping table in content controls, or even relying on the styling tags. But nothing gets us to a position where we can get access to the parent or detect if the selection is within a specific element, and upgrading the version of Word is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no direct way as 1.1 doesn't have table object/class.

You can first call getSelectedDataAsync(type: ooxml), then in the ooxml, you can analyze whether there is table out of the selection. But as mentioned above, you still can't get the table.